# Filter/Search objects in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just starting with ruby on rails, i got an issue that i could not resolve. First of all,  i got an list of Products and i would like to filter/show by its name, using a search field. But,  I'm getting this error, and i could not find an answer.

Error message:

[image: Error message]

commits on github that present my code:

https://github.com/miguelpimentel/FabricaDeMassas-ChefNery/commits/us%2326_pesquisar-produtos

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include the relevant part of your code in the question itself, and try to refrain from posting pictures with errors, post the error itself.

Comment: The most likely reason however is that you're missing a route in your routes.rb file

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following:

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id].to_i)
```

Converting your params[:id] to Integer is necessary.

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Comment: I think that's not the problem. I tried just for curiosity